# Fetch all dependencies, put them in a new local Maven repository using Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle project with several subprojects and many, many dependencies. I would like to have a simple way to tell Gradle to download *all* dependencies (including those under buildscript!) and put them in a local Maven/Ivy repository for later use. The Gradle script should then be able to pull all dependencies from the local repository.

Background: I need to build the application on a server which has absolutely no access to any public Maven repositories, so all dependencies must already be present on the host. I've tried a flat directory, but I have not found it easy to resolve the transitive dependencies, and managing them by hand is not an option. Copying the Gradle cache did not work, either.

Can anyone suggest something? Thanks.

Comment: This isn't supported out-of-the-box. You'd have to implement it on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, namely to install Apache Archive (http://archiva.apache.org/) locally and set it up as a proxy. Then I copied the entire installation to the target-server and disabled the remote repositories. The dependencies could then be fetched locally.